# Add all board types to the Arduino Stack Exchange site as tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I often have questions about the MKR GSM 1400 which I post on the Arduino Stack Exchange site. But unfortunately the closest tag for this is the MKR1000. Which is pretty similar, but not the same at all. The MKR1000 fetches data over Wi-Fi whereas the MKR1400 has a built in SIM module. So I wanted to ask if would be possible to add all the different Arduino products as tags to that Stack Exchange site?

The board types can be found here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products

Answer (score 1):

Privilege "create tags" is awarded at: 150 reputation.

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Do you have enough reputation?

Comment: I added the `mkr-gsm-1400` tag. You can assign it to your questions now.

Answer (score 0):

[Juraj's answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2539/7919) has explained about the "create tags" privilege and created [mkr-gsm-1400](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mkr-gsm-1400) tag.

But to answer your question,

> would [it] be possible to add all the different Arduino products as tags to that Stack Exchange site?

**Not really, tags can be only be created when there are questions to assign.** The Stack Exchange system doesn't allow anyone to create tags for non-existent questions, and those unassigned tags will be considered as "orphaned" and will be cleaned up daily.

Also, tags that have exactly one question are automatically pruned after six months, [**unless it has tag wiki**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).

That said, please consider to also complete the tag excerpt and tag wiki for [this tag](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/553) to save this tag!